# Variable not updated within handler.post's run method in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I created a new thread to handle my TCP management needs. I did this in order to keep the UI thread active while it's doing all sorts of socket magic. The problem I'm having is that the variable num used in ServerThread doesn't seem to updating within the handler.post()'s run method. It changes once but subsequent iterations within my while(true) loop no longer changes its value. However, outside handler.post() I noticed that it is changing properly. I have included a log command for logcat in order to see the values of num so that's why I know this is what is happening. The thing is, I need the variable num inside the run() method to update a few things in the UI thread.

May be there's something wrong with the way I declared num. I did not include in the code most of the things I think is irrelevant to my question, so if I missed something please let me now. This is my first adventure into android java threading so some help would be really appreciated. Just run out of mental energy tonight.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int num = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    //Other declarations


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        //Do bunch of things including starting ServerThread
        //and creating a TCP server socket
        }

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable{
       public void run(){
       // ...
       // Do bunch of stuff including waiting for a client to connect
       try{                         
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
         while(true){ 
           num = in.read();
           Log.e("MainActivity", "A:" +num);       //<-- WORKS FINE
           if(num == -1) //client socket closed
             break;
           handler.post(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 Log.e("MainActivity", "B:" +num); //<-- DOES NOT WORK FINE
                 //Do bunch of stuff here with the variable num 
                 //including updating the UI thread
              }
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
              // ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to declare your `num` variable as `volatile`

Comment: yes, I already tried `volatile`. Didn't work.

Comment: ok, then try to declare another variable inside the `while` loop and use it in the `Runable` object. `final int newNum = num;` and `Log.e("MainActivity", "B:" + newNum);`

Comment: I have this exact same issue. Declaring `volatile` did not work for me either.